# Can I print a Model diagram at 200% zoom without cutting off in vs 2010?

Tags: windows-xp, printer, printing, visual-studio-2010, zoom

In visual studio 2010, I would like to print a Model diagram (A .edmx file), at 200% zoom.
So I switch to landscape view and up the scale.
Printing goes as planned, except that whatever the zoom made to large gets cut off and not printed. I would like the excess areas to be spilled off onto additional pages rather than not printed at all.

My Environment: Windows XP SP3, Visual Studio 2010 SP1REL, Printer: Konica Minolta 501

Note: I tried printing to PDF using PDFLite and got the same issue.